MySQL 8.0.37 caused a severe memory leak
This is not a question but more of a public service announcement for anyone who is running MySQL 8.0.37 and has experienced an unstoppable memory leak.
We are on Amazon MySQL for RDS and upgraded from 8.0.28 to 8.0.37. After the upgrade we experienced a severe memory leak. Freeable memory kept falling and Swap Usage was rising. After months of trying to find the problem in our application and the parameters, we decided to give the next upgrade a chance. After upgrading to version 8.0.39 the problem had resolved itself.
Maybe this is helpful to anyone. Cheers

"This is not a question" - that's not a good start for a question on StackOverflow, especially one that is not related to programming

After upgrading to version 8.0.39 the memory leak had stopped.
